# Training API for Yolo (darknet)

Tags: c++, api, yolo, darknet

there is existing a API for Yolo to use it in own projects. Darknet offers an detector.
But I need to train a new custom dataset also by a method(parameters could be trainingspictures, configfile,...).

Is there also a API or did somebody a extension for the yolo-darknet?

Best regards,
Matthias

Answer (score 1):

> DarkHelp lets you skip those C function calls, and simplifies things with an extremely simple-to-use C++ API! The DarkHelp C++ library is available for both Linux and Windows.

https://www.ccoderun.ca/DarkHelp/api/Summary.html

It's the only thing i know.